# Plot the numerical integral which is sensitive to the lower limit

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Suppose the function

```
SingleCrossSection[Ss_, s2_, m_, m2_, 
   mp_] = -(1/(
    288 \[Pi]^3 s2^3 (Ss - 
       mp^2) Ss^4)) (12 Log[-((-m^2 + m2^2 + s2 + Sqrt[
         m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2])/(
        m^2 - m2^2 - s2 + Sqrt[
         m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2]))] (-3 (mp^2 - 
           Ss)^2 (m^2 + mp^2 - Ss) Log[(
          mp^2 - s2 - Ss + Sqrt[
           mp^4 - 2 (s2 + Ss) mp^2 + (s2 - Ss)^2])/(
          mp^2 - s2 - Ss - Sqrt[
           mp^4 - 2 (s2 + Ss) mp^2 + (s2 - Ss)^2])] s2^3 - (m^2 - 
           s2) Sqrt[
         mp^4 - 2 (s2 + Ss) mp^2 + (s2 - 
            Ss)^2] ((-2 mp^4 + (s2 + 4 Ss) mp^2 + s2^2 - 2 Ss^2 + 
              s2 Ss) m^4 + 
           s2 (-2 mp^4 + (4 Ss - 5 s2) mp^2 + s2^2 - 2 Ss^2 + 
              s2 Ss) m^2 + 
           s2^2 (mp^4 - 2 (s2 + Ss) mp^2 - 2 s2^2 + Ss^2 + 
              4 s2 Ss))) Ss^2 + (m^2 - 
        s2) (12 ((2 mp^6 - 3 (s2 + 2 Ss) mp^4 + 6 Ss^2 mp^2 + s2^3 - 
              2 Ss^3 + 3 s2 Ss^2) m^4 + 
           s2 (2 mp^6 + 3 (s2 - 2 Ss) mp^4 - 
              6 (s2^2 + Ss s2 - Ss^2) mp^2 + s2^3 - 2 Ss^3 + 
              3 s2 Ss^2) m^2 + 
           s2^2 (-mp^6 + 3 (s2 + Ss) mp^4 - 3 Ss^2 mp^2 - 2 s2^3 + 
              Ss^3 - 3 s2 Ss^2 + 6 s2^2 Ss)) Log[(

          mp^2 - s2 - Ss + Sqrt[
           mp^4 - 2 (s2 + Ss) mp^2 + (s2 - Ss)^2])/(
          mp^2 - s2 - Ss - Sqrt[
           mp^4 - 2 (s2 + Ss) mp^2 + (s2 - Ss)^2])] Ss^2 + 
        Sqrt[mp^4 - 
          2 (s2 + Ss) mp^2 + (s2 - 
            Ss)^2] ((-6 mp^8 + 
              3 (s2 + 24 Ss) mp^6 + (3 s2^2 - 27 Ss s2 - 
                 172 Ss^2) mp^4 + 
              Ss (-30 s2^2 - 19 Ss s2 + 152 Ss^2) mp^2 + 
              Ss^2 (35 s2^2 + 35 Ss s2 - 46 Ss^2)) m^4 + 
           s2 (3 mp^8 - 
              6 (s2 + 12 Ss) mp^6 + (3 s2^2 + 18 Ss s2 + 
                 110 Ss^2) mp^4 - 
              2 Ss (15 s2^2 + 17 Ss s2 + 8 Ss^2) mp^2 + 
              Ss^2 (11 s2^2 + 38 Ss s2 - 25 Ss^2)) m^2 - 
           s2^2 (-3 mp^8 - 
              3 (s2 - 24 Ss) mp^6 + (6 s2^2 + 63 Ss s2 - 
                 134 Ss^2) mp^4 + 
              Ss (-60 s2^2 + 19 Ss s2 + 64 Ss^2) mp^2 + 
              Ss^2 (46 s2^2 - 71 Ss s2 + Ss^2)))));
```

The variables are defined as

```
Ss>(m+m2+mp)^2 && s2 > (m+m2)^2 && s2 < (Sqrt[Ss]-mp)^2 && mp > 0 && m2 > 0 && m > 0
```

I need to check whether the definite integral of this function over s2 is positive defined. To do this, I just check the values of

```
NIntegrate[SingleCrossSection[Ss, s2, m, m2, 
   mp], {s2,(m+m2)^2,(Sqrt[Ss]-mp)^2}]
```

for particular ranges of m,m2,mp. I expect that the integral is positively defined in Ss. However, after using the code

```
Plot[NIntegrate[SingleCrossSection[Ss, s2, 0.1, 0.1, 
5], {s2, (0.1 + 0.1)^2, (Sqrt[Ss] - 5)^2}], {Ss, (0.1 + 0.1 + 
5)^2, 27.5}]
```

I obtained the graphic
[image: plot with negative]

telling that the function is not completely positively defined. That has surprised me. Just for fun I've decided to evaluate the integral with slightly modified lower limit:

```
Plot[NIntegrate[
  SingleCrossSection[Ss, s2, 0.1, 0.1, 
   5], {s2, (0.1 + 0.1)^2 + 0.01, (Sqrt[Ss] - 5)^2}], {Ss, (0.1 + 
    0.1 + 5)^2, 27.5}]
```

Not the plot is completely different - the negative part disappeared!
[image: plot, no negative]

Is this behavior just the consequence of the analytical behavior of the function, or is this the problem with *Mathematica*? Moreover, how to check definitely that the function is negative for some values of Ss?